# HTML table column with ghost column

Tags: html

I'm having a werid problem making a super simple table without any css mods.
The code is the following:

```html
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Count</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2<td>
            <td>ARGENTINA<td>
            <td>7379<td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>3<td>
            <td>CHILE<td>
            <td>6543<td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>4<td>
            <td>EGYPT<td>
            <td>6512<td>
         </tr>
      </table>
```

I'm getting crasy in trying to find what's wrong in this super simple code about why is it that the table header's columns refuse to align with its respective values?
It seems that there's an extra ghost column being created.
Can anyone explain, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your  lines are missing the closing . You have  where the closing tags should be.

```
<table>
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Count</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>ARGENTINA</td>
            <td>7379</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>CHILE</td>
            <td>6543</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>EGYPT</td>
            <td>6512</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I spend about 2 hours trying to figure out that and I just couldn't see the evident! Time to rest my eyes!

Comment: It happens. I find it really useful to bring someone over to just stand next to me while I explain whatever problem I'm having. It's amazing how quickly we find the problem ourselves. We just have to put ourselves into a teach mode.

Comment: Lack of closing something is not the issue. The issue is the presence of spurious `<td>` tags, which of course start new cells. They were apparently meant to be `</td>` tags, but that’s not the point, and closing `</td>` tags are always optional (except in XHTML).

Answer (score 0):

Your  doesn't have a closing tag.

Try this:

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Count</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>ARGENTINA</td>
        <td>7379</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>CHILE</td>
        <td>6543</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>EGYPT</td>
        <td>6512</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Then it looks like it tries to create closing tags for each... And as a result you are ending up with weird extra columns.

Comment: Thank you! I spend about 2 hours trying to figure out that and I just couldn't see the evident! Time to rest my eyes!